# No UI components while importing a library in Scene Builder

Tags: javafx, font-awesome, scenebuilder

I am trying to import a custom UI library, exactly the fontawesome icons to the Scene Builder while developing a Java app, however there are no UI components to select after I am addding the library. I am using JDK 10 and Scene Builder 11.

In the IntelliJ's Maven POM file have added the dependecies like following:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
<artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
<version>11.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
<artifactId>ikonli-fontawesome-pack</artifactId>
<version>11.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Steps I am taking to add the library are presented below:

[Adding the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzQeL.png)

[Selecting fontawesome pack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEbq2.png)

[No UI components to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CKDO.png)

I have read that no visible components may be related with incorrect versions of the fontawesome library and scene builder but as you can see they are both versions 11.

Do you have any ideas how to resolve my problem or maybe on the way I have ignored something important accidentally?

Comment: Have you tried importing `ikonli-javafx`? That works for me. The icon artifacts may not contain controls.

Comment: @JoséPereda it works! Thank you!